# returning an array of objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I need to pass an array of mailobjects from my rails mailer class to the corresponding controller which i thought should work if i just do

```
class foo < Actionmailer::Base

    def bar(...)
        mails_array = Array.new
        return mails_array
    end
```

but as the controller gets `mails_array` via

```
@mails = Array.new
@mails.concat(foo.bar(...))
```

i get a:

> TypeError in mailsController#index
>   can't convert Mail::Message into Array

did i miss something??
I would expect to have the mails_array in mails and can't understand why it is not.

Comment: `concat` why that's not passing my mind, haha tqq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `foo.bar`, but `bar` is defined as instance method, not class method. Try

```
class foo < Actionmailer::Base      

    def self.bar(...)
        mails_array = Array.new
        return mails_array
    end
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Array#concat` expects the argument to be an array but you're passing a `Mail::Message`. Try the following:

```
@mails << foo.bar(...)
```

or

```
@mails.push(foo.bar(...))
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help.. the array will be filled but just with the first element out of `mails_array`    
although it should be the whole array